# Как перенастроить компиляцию pascal в VScode на Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, компиляция, pascalabc.net

Суть проблемы: `VScode` компилирует фалы `.pas` как надо, но запустить пытается `.exe` файл через `mono`.

Команда, которую использует VScode: `fpc "/home/kado/Документы/VSprojects/main.pas" && mono "/home/kado/Документы/VSprojects/main.exe"`

Команды, которую нужно использовать мне: `fpc file.pas && ./file`

Как перенастроить компиляцию в `VScode`? Либо, может есть другое решение? Потому, что мне кажется, что вывод программы будет не в `OUTPUT`, а в `TERMINAL` `VScod'a`.